# z-index for different positioned elements

Tags: html, css

Here, the div containing `<p>` (defintion) is to be placed behind the div containing the image (image). I tried absolute positioning on definition div so that it should appear on the same stack as image's, like mentioned below.

```
definition {
position: absolute;
top:0
}
```

But, then setting z-index doesn't work anymore. If anyone has any solution, please help me. Here's my entire code.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outer_container">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="image">
                <img src="work_pic.jpg" />
                <div id="definition">
                    <p>Nothing</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="image">
                <img src="work_pic.jpg" />
                <div id="definition">
                    <p>Nothing</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="image">
                <img src="work_pic.jpg" />
                <div id="definition">
                    <p>Nothing</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer_container {
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

#definition {
    background-color: red;
}

#image {
}
```

Comment: A `z-index` requires positioning, aside from that your first instance of referencing definition doesn't include the hashtag, as it's an id.. `#definition{}`.

Comment: so is there any other way?

Comment: to bring #definition backwards?

Comment: This is what your current coding looks like.. http://jsfiddle.net/bVe7H/ what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to bring definition backwards, so that whenever i hover over the image, defintion appears.:-(

Comment: this is what i came up with `#image img:hover {
        opacity: 0.1;
        transition: 2s all;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Before going to Z-index, first you have some basic corrections to be made.

In a html document the id used must be unique. for repeating naming convention you should use class.

in your code for container and image use class.
like
class="container"
class="image"

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes - hope it answers your question.

CSS:

```
#outer_container {
 margin:auto; // margin:auto to center the div
 width:50%; 
}

#outer_container .container { // The Boxes
 margin: 5px 10px 0px 0px;
 float:left;
}

.image {  // Your Picture ( used div instead of pic - better testing
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

.definition { // Your "display item will be here"
 background-color: red;
 display:none; // display:none because u want to display it later
} 

.image:hover .definition { 
//hover the image .image:hover and do something with .definition
 display:block;
 // display:block - when u hover the .img element .definition appears
}
```

---

you should use classes in css if you use the style more than once:

- `#id if you use it once`
- `.class if u use it more than one time`

and don't forget the `clear:both` if u let things float :)

[Working Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bVe7H/1/)